Proving a commutative ring with unity is an integral domain given its prime ideal is an integral domain
I am trying to prove the following statement: If a prime ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ with unity is an integral domain, then $R$ is an integral domain.
Here is my attempt so far:
Suppose $R$ is not an integral domain. Then there exist non-zero elements $a,b\in R$ such that $ab = 0$.
We consider the following cases:

If both $a,b\in I$, then since $I$ is an integral domain, this leads to a contradiction.
If both $a,b\notin I$, then considering their images $\overline{a}=a + I$ and $\overline{b}=b + I$ in the quotient ring $R/I$. Since $ab = 0$, we have $\overline{a}\overline{b}=(a + I)(b + I)=ab + I = 0+I=\overline{0}$ in $R/I$. Since $R/I$ is an integral domain, either $\overline{a}=\overline{0}$ (i.e., $a\in I$) or $\overline{b}=\overline{0}$ (i.e., $b\in I$), which is a contradiction.

However, I am stuck on the third case: If $a\in I$ and $b\notin I$, how can I show that this also leads to a contradiction? Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

@AlessandroFenu Thank you for your reply. I'm still a bit confused. Since $I$ is an integral domain, it indeed has no zero divisors within $I$ itself. But how does this fact extend to show that $I$ contains no zero divisors of the whole ring $R$? The property of $I$ being an integral domain only directly tells us about non - zero products within $I$. Could you please elaborate on this step? I really appreciate it.

Let $R$ and $S$ be integral domains,  then $R \times S$ is a commutative ring which is not an integral domain, but the prime ideal $R \times \{0\}$ is an integral domain.

Thanks for giving the counter example!
